# Missed notification from Monitor.PulseAll

Tags: c#, multithreading

I tried to use Monitor.PulaseAll to notify user thread of new data, but the result shows not even a single thread successfully received every new data notification.

```
public class CTest
{
    CDataProducer m_DataProducer = new CDataProducer();

    public void startTest()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Thread th = new Thread(userThead);
            th.Name = "Thread" + (i + 1).ToString();
            th.Start();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            m_DataProducer.ProduceNewData();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        DateTime dtBeg = DateTime.Now;
        while (true)
        {
            if ((DateTime.Now - dtBeg).TotalSeconds >= 10)
            {
                break;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }

    }

    private void userThead()
    {
        int cProcessed = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1);

            double dData;
            if (m_DataProducer.WaitData(out dData))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + ":" + dData.ToString());
                cProcessed++;
                if (dData >= 5)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + ": Exited at " + dData.ToString() + ", N=" + cProcessed.ToString());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [Fact]
    public void TEST_pulseall()
    {
        CTest test = new CTest();
        test.startTest();
    }
}


class CDataProducer
{
    private object m_NewObj = new object();

    private object m_LockData = new object();
    private double m_Data_d = 0;

    public CDataProducer()
    {
    }

    public void ProduceNewData()
    {
        lock (m_NewObj)
        {
            if (Monitor.TryEnter(m_LockData, 5000))
            {
                m_Data_d++;
                Monitor.Exit(m_LockData);
                Monitor.PulseAll(m_NewObj);
            }
        }
    }
    public bool WaitData(out double dData)
    {
        bool bRet = false;

        dData = 0;

        lock (m_NewObj)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Monitor.Wait(m_NewObj, 1))
                {
                    if (Monitor.TryEnter(m_LockData, 5000))
                    {
                        dData = m_Data_d;
                        Monitor.Exit(m_LockData);
                    }
                    //Monitor.PulseAll(m_NewObj);
                    bRet = true;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
            }
        }

        return bRet;
    }
}
```

one of my results shows:

```
Thread2:1
Thread3:1
Thread1:1
Thread1:2
Thread4:2
Thread5:4
Thread3:4
Thread4:4
Thread1:4
Thread4:6
Thread4: Exited at 6, N=3
thread  0x325c code 259 (0x103)  terminated.
Thread2:7
Thread2: Exited at 7, N=2
```

the thread 2 only processed data "1".
and thread 1 process "1", "2", "4", and it missed "3" and "5".
and obviously most of the data had been missed.

I event delayed 1sec after each new data is produced to make time for user thead to be able to receive notification and process data.

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Somewhere you need to keep track of what information each thread has already processed so that you can make a decision of whether some information is new or not. Your code makes no attempt to do this.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anything wrong?

Well, it seems according to your question, there is. :) It does depend on what behavior you really want, but I gather you're not getting what you want. So, yes…that'd probably qualify as "wrong". :)

From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.pulse(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The Monitor class does not maintain state indicating that the Pulse method has been called. Thus, if you call Pulse when no threads are waiting, the next thread that calls Wait blocks as if Pulse had never been called.

The issue here is that you do nothing to ensure that the producer only calls `Pulse()` when there are consumers waiting, and more importantly, to ensure that it waits until the current data has been consumed before producing the next data element.

It's hard to know exactly what you really wanted. The code you posted, even if made to "work", in that all data elements are observed, still seems a bit odd in that you have five consumers, all of which will consume the same data element. That said, with that understanding, here's a version of the code that "works":

```
class CDataProducer
{
    private readonly object _writeMonitor = new object();
    private readonly object _readMonitor = new object();
    private readonly object _lock = new object();

    private double _data;

    public bool IsDone { get; private set; }

    public void ProduceNewData()
    {
        lock (_writeMonitor)
        {
            if (!IsDone)
            {
                lock (_lock)
                {
                    _data++;
                }
                lock (_readMonitor) Monitor.PulseAll(_readMonitor);
                Monitor.Wait(_writeMonitor);
            }
        }
    }

    public bool WaitData(out double result)
    {
        lock (_readMonitor)
        {
            Monitor.Wait(_readMonitor);
            lock (_lock)
            {
                result = _data;
            }
            lock (_writeMonitor) Monitor.Pulse(_writeMonitor);
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void Done()
    {
        lock (_writeMonitor)
        {
            IsDone = true;
            Monitor.Pulse(_writeMonitor);
        }
    }
}

public static void startTest()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Thread th = new Thread(userThead);
        th.Name = "Thread" + (i + 1).ToString();
        th.IsBackground = true;
        th.Start();
    }

    Func<Task> waitAndDone = async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        m_DataProducer.Done();
    };

    Task waitAndDoneTask = waitAndDone();

    for (int i = 0; i < 7 && !m_DataProducer.IsDone; i++)
    {
        m_DataProducer.ProduceNewData();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    waitAndDoneTask.Wait();
}
```

I made no changes to the `userThead()` method, so didn't bother to include it in the above.

Notes:

- The primary change here is to have two different monitors, so that the producer and consumers can signal back and forth with each other. Having written a value, the producer will not proceed until it's been signaled by a consumer (technically, it ought to wait until *all* consumers have signaled, but this works "well enough" for the purpose of illustration).
- I also revised the termination condition in a couple of ways. First, the delay is done using a timer rather than polling the clock. Second, because the producer will block until it's signaled, part of termination involves not just setting a flag to tell the producer loop to stop, but also to signal the monitor to wake it up so it can check that flag.

A more typical producer/consumer scenario, even one involving multiple consumers, would have each produced element consumed by only *one* consumer. At the same time, typically the producer and consumers would not be forced to operate in lock-step. Instead, a queue would act as a buffer, to allow the consumer to produce independently of the consumers, and allowing the consumers to consume new data elements as they are provided.

Here's a version of the producer code that works that way:

```
class CDataProducer
{
    public bool IsDone { get; private set; }

    private double _data;
    private readonly Queue<double> _values = new Queue<double>();
    private readonly object _lock = new object();

    public void Done()
    {
        IsDone = true;
    }

    public void ProduceNewData()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            _values.Enqueue(++_data);
            Monitor.Pulse(_lock);
        }
    }

    public bool WaitData(out double value)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            while (_values.Count == 0)
            {
                Monitor.Wait(_lock);
            }

            value = _values.Dequeue();

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

You may notice that this approach is actually much simpler. The queue obviates the need for the producer and consumers to alternate execution, so only one monitor is required (instead of *three* in the other version). And because the producer doesn't wait, there's no need to signal it just to shut down.

Of course, when terminating, it's possible there are still elements in the queue, and consumers still running. Again, the above suffices for illustration, but a real-world scenario might include additional logic to address this. As it happens, .NET provides a built-in class that handles all of this very gracefully, called `BlockingCollection<T>`.

Here is a somewhat different variation of your original code illustrating how that might be used:

```
class CDataProducer
{
    private readonly BlockingCollection<double> _queue = new BlockingCollection<double>();
    private double _value;

    public bool IsDone { get; private set; }

    public void Done()
    {
        IsDone = true;
        _queue.CompleteAdding();
    }

    public void ProduceNewData()
    {
        _queue.Add(++_value);
    }

    public void Consumer()
    {
        foreach (double value in _queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + ":" + value);
        }
    }
}

public static void startTest()
{
    CDataProducer dataProducer = new CDataProducer();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Thread th = new Thread(dataProducer.Consumer);
        th.Name = "Thread" + (i + 1).ToString();
        th.Start();
    }

    Func<Task> waitAndDone = async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        dataProducer.Done();
    };

    Task waitAndDoneTask = waitAndDone();

    for (int i = 0; i < 7 && !dataProducer.IsDone; i++)
    {
        dataProducer.ProduceNewData();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    waitAndDoneTask.Wait();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    startTest();
}
```

In the above, I don't even use the consumer method you wrote. Instead, I added a `Consumer()` method to the `CDataProducer` class, and that method handles consuming.

The key here is the `GetConsumingEnumerable()` method. This returns an `IEnumerable<T>` instance that will block until data is available, and will terminate when the `CompleteAdding()` method is called on the collection object.

If you didn't want the consumer code in the `CDataProducer` class itself, it would be simple enough to add a method for that class to return the `GetConsumingEnumerable()` result, so that code outside the class could implement the same loop.

*(Note: the above code omits some concurrency constructs that would normally be important. For example, the `IsDone` property is not using a field declared as `volatile`. In the code above, running on Intel x86 architecture, it's not needed, but strictly speaking the code isn't correct without it. In the above, I tried to focus just on the specific task at hand, i.e. a discussion of the producer/consumer pattern in the context of the code you originally posted.)*

Comment: the same new data are to be processed by multiple threads, for example UI, calculation, logging and so on. because new data production interval is not so short  that every worker thread is expected to finish new data one by one, at best. I have intended to use ManualResetEvent for each worker thread, but was [against to do so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42761940/multiple-manualresetevent). If Event is used, every subscriber would be definitely notified I think.

Comment: @Chengting: _"the same new data are to be processed by multiple threads"_ -- I would still have only one consumer. Have the single consumer receive each new data element, and then use `Task` to dispatch separate operations for each element as desired. That's assuming it really makes sense to do all those things concurrently in the first place. The examples you gave include only one CPU-costly item (_"calculation"_), so for those three, you could easily combine them into a single thread. UI and logging should not be worth dedicating an entire consumer thread to each.

Comment: sure, one consumer and dispatch from there, and also think about if it is really necessary to different threads.

Comment: Even though there might not be real need for concurrency, it seems good for me 1. treat each woker as an independnt unit  2. if there is something wrong with logging, I dont want the file operation exceptions handling mixed with other task processing.   I expect: thread (consumer) can lightly poll new data, and if no data just do something else, and then poll again.

Comment: As for dispatching, every time a new worker is there, I have to add new dispatching code. So I prefer just add polling data for the worker itself, confine the consumer-producer relationship inside the worker.

Comment: Another matter is, sometimes it is not that every new data has to be processed without missing strictly. for example UI, if when it is ready to process, another newer data is available, it only needs to process the newest data. there is no need to queue every produced data.

Comment: These make me think that individual ManualResetEvent object for each worker thread is simple and effective.

Answer (score 0):

You will miss a `Monitor.Pulse` if you aren't waiting on it exactly when it happens.

You would need to lock `m_NewObj`, check if data was ready with a flag or count, then wait if wasn't ready.  Meanwhile your data producers would lock `m_NewObj`, set the flag/count, then `Pulse`.  If your consumer was waiting, it would wake up and see data.  If it wasn't waiting, when it checked next the data would be ready.

I would recommend you use `SemaphoreSlim` for this kind of consumer-producer thread synchronization rather than `Monitor`, it is simpler.

Comment: I want to avoid polling operations of worker thread, thinking it would be optimal if it can be notified of data availability. sure, the Monitor.Pulse will be missed if I am not waiting on it when it happens, maybe this is waht the "pulse" means.  but I can not imagine how semaphore can fullfil this job.

Comment: Both mechanisms would involve polling, but both would be efficient waits while polling.  Either you will be efficiently waiting on Monitor.Wait if polling showed no data available, or you would be efficiently waiting Sempahore.Wait() for data to become available.  Semaphore.Wait is simpler because it combines the "if data is ready continue immediately otherwise wait" into a single step.

Comment: in fact for the worker thread, I want to poll with as little cost as possible, and, if no data is available, just do something else (e.g. for UI, display other new data), and then back to poll new data again (periodically, by a timer ).